# Sass looping through class names starting with number

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I am looping through a list of names in sass and it seems that the sass is breaking when it arrives at a point where the class names starts with a number. Infact when i commented out the class names starting with a numeric value, the sass compilation worked fine. That said i cannot rename the class names. How I can make it work? Below is the code im trying:

```
@each $car in
  bmwwhite
  hondared
  //22ltr-porche
  //30ltr-cossworth
 {
  .#{$car} {
    background:url(/img/cars/#{$car}.jpg) no-repeat 
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML5 is fine with starting ID's and class names with digits these days, but CSS isn't ([Here's some info about all this](http://benfrain.com/when-and-where-you-can-use-numbers-in-id-and-class-names/)).

Sass probably wouldn't allow you to create invalid CSS selector, such as `.22ltr-porche` so that makes sense. Though there are ways to get around it.

You could try this:

```
@each $car in
  bmwwhite
  hondared
  22ltr-porche
  30ltr-cossworth
 {
  [class="#{$car}"] {
    background:url(/img/cars/#{$car}.jpg) no-repeat 
  }
 }
```

That will create a selector that looks like this `[class="22ltr-porche"]` and [Sass is OK with that.](http://sassmeister.com/gist/e3fdc264caaaf74a9687)

Unqualified attribute selectors like this tends to be very slow though. You should try to combine the attribute selector with something with more specificity. Here's an [example plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/D2a7q4C7xuM15sJqT4bZ?p=preview).

Comment: The output of that is [class="bmwwhite"] {
  background:

so the output is wrong in the .css file :/

Comment: no it doesnt because the output should be .bmwwhite { background:...........} 

instead the output is coming like this  [class="bmwwhite"] { background:.......}

Comment: Well, that should be all right, like [type="text"]. Attributes can be accessed like that.

Answer (score 1):

The class you're trying to generate is invalid.  Running it through the validator will give this error:

> In CSS1, a class name could start with a digit (".55ft"), unless it was a dimension (".55in"). In CSS2, such classes are parsed as unknown dimensions (to allow for future additions of new units) To make "22ltr-porche" a valid class, CSS2 requires the first digit to be escaped ".\32 2ltr-porche"  [22ltr-porche]

So, we need to escape the leading number like it says:

```
@function escape_leading_numbers($s) {
  $first-char: str_slice(#{$s}, 0, 1);
  $found: index('1' '2' '3' '4' '5' '6' '7' '8' '9' '0', $first-char);
  @return if($found, unquote(str-insert(str-slice(#{$s}, 2), "\\3#{$first-char} ", 1)), $s);
}

$name: '007';

.#{escape_leading_numbers($name)} {
  color: red;
}

@each $car in
  bmwwhite
  hondared
  22ltr-porche
  30ltr-cossworth
 {
  .#{escape_leading_numbers($car)} {
    background:url(/img/cars/#{$car}.jpg) no-repeat
  }
 }
```

Output:

```
.bmwwhite {
  background: url(/img/cars/bmwwhite.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.hondared {
  background: url(/img/cars/hondared.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.\32 2ltr-porche {
  background: url(/img/cars/22ltr-porche.jpg) no-repeat;
}

.\33 0ltr-cossworth {
  background: url(/img/cars/30ltr-cossworth.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

http://sassmeister.com/gist/e07d3fd4f67452412ad0